# Skel framework multi level/dropdown navigation

Tags: javascript, css, skel

I am currently using skel framework for my basic website. I need to make the nav into multi level nav (dropdown). Is there a built in feature or Do I need to include some plugin? With my current setting, single level nav is working well, but when I nest the UL & LI tags, it breaks the page.

```js
/* skel-baseline v2.0.3 | (c) n33 | getskel.com | MIT licensed */

(function($) {

 skel.init({
  reset: 'full',
  breakpoints: {
   global: {
    href: 'assets/css/style.css',
    containers: 1400,
    grid: { gutters: ['40px', 0] }
   },
   xlarge: {
    media: '(max-width: 1680px)',
    href: 'assets/css/style-xlarge.css',
    containers: 1200
   },
   large: {
    media: '(max-width: 1280px)',
    href: 'assets/css/style-large.css',
    containers: 960,
    grid: { gutters: ['40px', 0] },
    viewport: { scalable: false }
   },
   medium: {
    media: '(max-width: 980px)',
    href: 'assets/css/style-medium.css',
    containers: '90%'
   },
   small: {
    media: '(max-width: 736px)',
    href: 'assets/css/style-small.css',
    containers: '90%',
    grid: { gutters: ['40px', 0] }
   },
   xsmall: {
    media: '(max-width: 480px)',
    href: 'assets/css/style-xsmall.css'
   }
  },
  plugins: {
   layers: {
    config: {
     mode: 'transform'
    },
    navPanel: {
     animation: 'pushX',
     breakpoints: 'medium',
     clickToHide: true,
     height: '100%',
     hidden: true,
     html: '<div data-action="moveElement" data-args="nav"></div>',
     orientation: 'vertical',
     position: 'top-right',
     side: 'right',
     width: 250
    },
    navButton: {
     breakpoints: 'medium',
     height: '4em',
     html: '<span class="toggle" data-action="toggleLayer" data-args="navPanel"></span>',
     position: 'top-right',
     side: 'top',
     width: '6em'
    }
   }
  }
 });

 $(function() {

  var $window = $(window),
   $body = $('body');

  // Disable animations/transitions until the page has loaded.
   $body.addClass('is-loading');

   $window.on('load', function() {
    $body.removeClass('is-loading');
   });

 });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
/* skel-baseline v2.0.3 | (c) n33 | getskel.com | MIT licensed */

/* Resets (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ | v2.0 | 20110126 | License: none (public domain)) */

 html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline;}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block;}body{line-height:1;}ol,ul{list-style:none;}blockquote,q{quotes:none;}blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:'';content:none;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}body{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none}

/* Box Model */

 *, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }

/* Container */

 .container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

  /* width: (containers) */
  width: 1200px;
 }

 /* Modifiers */

  /* 125% */
   .container.\31 25\25 {
    width: 100%;

    /* max-width: (containers * 1.25) */
    max-width: 1500px;

    /* min-width: (containers) */
    min-width: 1200px;
   }

  /* 75% */
   .container.\37 5\25 {

    /* width: (containers * 0.75) */
    width: 900px;

   }

  /* 50% */
   .container.\35 0\25 {

    /* width: (containers * 0.50) */
    width: 600px;

   }

  /* 25% */
   .container.\32 5\25 {

    /* width: (containers * 0.25) */
    width: 300px;

   }

/* Grid */

 .row {
  border-bottom: solid 1px transparent;
 }

 .row > * {
  float: left;
 }

 .row:after, .row:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
 }

 .row.uniform > * > :first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
 }

 .row.uniform > * > :last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
 }

 /* Gutters */

  /* Normal */

   .row > * {
    /* padding: (gutters.horizontal) 0 0 (gutters.vertical) */
    padding: 0 0 0 2em;
   }

   .row {
    /* margin: -(gutters.horizontal) 0 -1px -(gutters.vertical) */
    margin: 0 0 -1px -2em;
   }

   .row.uniform > * {
    /* padding: (gutters.vertical) 0 0 (gutters.vertical) */
    padding: 2em 0 0 2em;
   }

   .row.uniform {
    /* margin: -(gutters.vertical) 0 -1px -(gutters.vertical) */
    margin: -2em 0 -1px -2em;
   }

  /* 200% */

   .row.\32 00\25 > * {
    /* padding: (gutters.horizontal) 0 0 (gutters.vertical) */
    padding: 0 0 0 4em;
   }

   .row.\32 00\25 {
    /* margin: -(gutters.horizontal) 0 -1px -(gutters.vertical) */
    margin: 0 0 -1px -4em;
   }

   .row.uniform.\32 00\25 > * {
    /* padding: (gutters.vertical) 0 0 (gutters.vertical) */
    padding: 4em 0 0 4em;
   }

   .row.uniform.\32 00\25 {
    /* margin: -(gutters.vertical) 0 -1px -(gutters.vertical) */
    margin: -4em 0 -1px -4em;
   }

  /* 150% */

   .row.\31 50\25 > * {
    /* padding: (gutters.horizontal) 0 0 (gutters.vertical) */
    padding: 0 0 0 1.5em;
   }

   .row.\31 50\25 {
    /* margin: -(gutters.horizontal) 0 -1px -(gutters.vertical) */
    margin: 0 0 -1px -1.5em;
   }

   .row.uniform.\31 50\25 > * {
    /* padding: (gutters.vertical) 0 0 (gutters.vertical) */
    padding: 1.5em 0 0 1.5em;
   }

   .row.uniform.\31 50\25 {
    /* margin: -(gutters.vertical) 0 -1px -(gutters.vertical) */
    margin: -1.5em 0 -1px -1.5em;
   }

  /* 50% */

   .row.\35 0\25 > * {
    /* padding: (gutters.horizontal) 0 0 (gutters.vertical) */
    padding: 0 0 0 1em;
   }

   .row.\35 0\25 {
    /* margin: -(gutters.horizontal) 0 -1px -(gutters.vertical) */
    margin: 0 0 -1px -1em;
   }

   .row.uniform.\35 0\25 > * {
    /* padding: (gutters.vertical) 0 0 (gutters.vertical) */
    padding: 1em 0 0 1em;
   }

   .row.uniform.\35 0\25 {
    /* margin: -(gutters.vertical) 0 -1px -(gutters.vertical) */
    margin: -1em 0 -1px -1em;
   }

  /* 25% */

   .row.\32 5\25 > * {
    /* padding: (gutters.horizontal) 0 0 (gutters.vertical) */
    padding: 0 0 0 0.5em;
   }

   .row.\32 5\25 {
    /* margin: -(gutters.horizontal) 0 -1px -(gutters.vertical) */
    margin: 0 0 -1px -0.5em;
   }

   .row.uniform.\32 5\25 > * {
    /* padding: (gutters.vertical) 0 0 (gutters.vertical) */
    padding: 0.5em 0 0 0.5em;
   }

   .row.uniform.\32 5\25 {
    /* margin: -(gutters.vertical) 0 -1px -(gutters.vertical) */
    margin: -0.5em 0 -1px -0.5em;
   }

  /* 0% */

   .row.\30 \25 > * {
    padding: 0;
   }

   .row.\30 \25 {
    margin: 0 0 -1px 0;
   }

 /* Cells */

  .\31 2u, .\31 2u\24 { width: 100%; clear: none; margin-left: 0; }
  .\31 1u, .\31 1u\24 { width: 91.6666666667%; clear: none; margin-left: 0; }
  .\31 0u, .\31 0u\24 { width: 83.3333333333%; clear: none; margin-left: 0; }
  .\39 u, .\39 u\24 { width: 75%; clear: none; margin-left: 0; }
  .\38 u, .\38 u\24 { width: 66.6666666667%; clear: none; margin-left: 0; }
  .\37 u, .\37 u\24 { width: 58.3333333333%; clear: none; margin-left: 0; }
  .\36 u, .\36 u\24 { width: 50%; clear: none; margin-left: 0; }
  .\35 u, .\35 u\24 { width: 41.6666666667%; clear: none; margin-left: 0; }
  .\34 u, .\34 u\24 { width: 33.3333333333%; clear: none; margin-left: 0; }
  .\33 u, .\33 u\24 { width: 25%; clear: none; margin-left: 0; }
  .\32 u, .\32 u\24 { width: 16.6666666667%; clear: none; margin-left: 0; }
  .\31 u, .\31 u\24 { width: 8.3333333333%; clear: none; margin-left: 0; }

  .\31 2u\24 + *,
  .\31 1u\24 + *,
  .\31 0u\24 + *,
  .\39 u\24 + *,
  .\38 u\24 + *,
  .\37 u\24 + *,
  .\36 u\24 + *,
  .\35 u\24 + *,
  .\34 u\24 + *,
  .\33 u\24 + *,
  .\32 u\24 + *,
  .\31 u\24 + * {
   clear: left;
  }

  .\-11u { margin-left: 91.6666666667% }
  .\-10u { margin-left: 83.3333333333% }
  .\-9u { margin-left: 75% }
  .\-8u { margin-left: 66.6666666667% }
  .\-7u { margin-left: 58.3333333333% }
  .\-6u { margin-left: 50% }
  .\-5u { margin-left: 41.6666666667% }
  .\-4u { margin-left: 33.3333333333% }
  .\-3u { margin-left: 25% }
  .\-2u { margin-left: 16.6666666667% }
  .\-1u { margin-left: 8.3333333333% }
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#top">Top</a></li>
      <li><a href="#content">Content</a></li>
      <li><a href="#elements">Elements</a>
<ul><li>Link 1</li><li>link 2</li><li>Link 3</li></ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#grid">Grid System</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://getskel.com" class="button special">Download</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no support built into the skel.js or css that supports any drop down menus. You need to either incorporate a dropdown menu plugin (preferably a jQuery plugin, since you're already using jQuery) or code your own.

Answer (score 0):

It's not built into skel, but it exists.  The author of skel wrote dropotron, which adds dropdown menus to jquery and incorporates easily with the rest of skel plugins.

https://github.com/n33/jquery.dropotron